# Time input from the system in java

Tags: java, constructor

I want to display a countdown of `10` secs. like `10-9-8-7...` by taking time from the system in java. How can i achieve it? Can you give me the source code for it?

Comment: Please visit FAQ of this page.

Comment: Translation: 'Can you do it for me so I don't have to do anything'

Answer (score 1):

The combination of a decrementing `for` loop (from 10 to 1) and [`Thread.sleep`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long%29) should suit your needs.

Comment: `Thread#sleep` doesn't guarantee that the application will truly sleep by the number of milliseconds you provide as argument. Refer to the documentation you've posted: *subject to the **precision and accuracy** of system timers and schedulers*.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza That's true but for the purposes of this task it should be accurate enough.

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage the `Timer`'s `scheduleAtFixedRate` method which takes the initial `delay` and the `period` per which the task should be run

```
  final Timer t = new Timer();
  t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

        int i = 10;
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println(i);
            i--;
            if(i <= 0) {
                t.cancel();
            }
        }
    }, 1000, 1000);
```

Comment: Why does everyone use Timer with empty contructor? you can specify both delay and Runnable in the constructor. Edit: oh wait, which timer? util or swing? I prefer swing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;


public class TimeCal {
static int interval;
static Timer timer;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Input in seconds => : ");
    String secs = sc.nextLine();
    int delay = 1000;
    int period = 1000;
    timer = new java.util.Timer();
    interval = Integer.parseInt( secs );
    System.out.println(secs);
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            System.out.println(setInterval());

        }
    }, delay, period);
}
private static final int setInterval(){
    if( interval== 1) timer.cancel();
    return --interval;
}
}
```